# Symlink are using both locations?

Tags: mysql, webserver, symbolic-link

I've researched and didn't find any answers, so I decided to ask here.
The `/dev/sda2` disk of my WHM/Cpanel webserver got 100% full.
The `/var` folder is on the `/dev/sda2` disk and I've found that the reason of 100% full disk is the `/var/lib/mysql` folder.

To fix it I need to move the `/var/lib/mysql` folder from `/dev/sda2` to `/home` where I have a lot of space in disk.

Then I used the command lines:

```
service mysql stop
cp -r -p /var/lib/mysql/ /home/databasesmysql/
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.backup/
ln -s /home/databasesmysql/ /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

Ok, now to check if its running at the new location I just renamed the `/var/lib/mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql.backup` and MySQL stopped working.

Also when I rename the `/home/databasesmysql` folder MySQL also stop to work.

I don't know whats happening, the symlink are using both locations?

Comment: Reading `/var/log/mysql.log` and/or `/var/log/mysql.err` (likely the latter, in this case) can help determine what is *actually* going wrong. I suspect its a permissions issue.

Comment: Before starting copying / moving directories, I would have first checked if MySQL was really stopped. In last Ubuntu version (14.04) Mysql can be started via Upstart that will restart it automatically if it founds that the process is gone. In this case you have to stop it by doing `stop mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ln -s` with the arguments the wrong way round. Think `cp` when you use `ln`: the source comes first, the destination last.

You want to have a link `/var/lib/mysql` pointing to actual directory `/home/databasesmysql`. If you were copying you would do:

```
cp -r /home/databasesmysql /var/lib/mysql
```

So with `ln -s` you do:

```
ln -s /home/databasesmysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the directory `/home/databasesmysql` exist before running the commands?

If it did, the directory
`/var/lib/mysql` was **not copied *to*** `/home/databasesmysql`,
it was **copied *into*** `/home/databasesmysql`,
so the copy is named `/home/databasesmysql/mysql`, instead of `/home/databasesmysql`.

That would mean the link `/var/lib/mysql` does not point to the right directory, of course.